# How do I enable Aerospike rack-awareness with a rolling deploy?

Tags: aerospike

I just upgraded my Aerospike cluster and would like to turn on rack-awareness now (unicast/mesh).

I tested the config with a fresh cluster, so I know I got that part working.

However, if I restart one node on paxos v4 (and cluster{}), it does not join the cluster failing on incompatible paxos.

How can I get to rack-awareness w/o restarting them all at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Presently, as of [3.12.0](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/3.12.0/), changing to Rack Aware requires restarting the cluster.